# How do I calculate probabilities in a 6/49 numbers game?

Tags: probability

A numbers game called the 49s has 49 numbers (1-49). 6 winning numbers are drawn from 49.

Customers can bet on 1,2,3,4 or 5 numbers at a time. For instance if a customer selects number 8, if number 8 is drawn they win. Likewise if the customer selects numbers 8 & 9, if both numbers are drawn they win.

I would like to know how to calculate the probability of correctly selecting 1,2,3 4 or 5 numbers. I understand that there are 13,983,816 different combinations of 6 numbers from 49, but I don't know how to calculate how many of them contain the number 8 for instance, or how many contain both numbers 8 & 9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mathematics SE! It might be easier to think of it in probabilities. If we bet on 1 number what is the probability of getting one right? Now what if we bet on 2 numbers? I think focussing on the different combinations is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{49}k$ ways to select $k$ numbers from $49$ numbers, where $\binom nk$ is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). There are $\binom6k$ ways to select $k$ numbers from $6$ numbers. Thus the probability of selecting $k$ numbers that are among the $6$ numbers drawn is

$$
\frac{\binom6k}{\binom{49}k}=\frac{6!(49-k)!}{49!(6-k)!}\;.
$$